# Receiving Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function upload() on a non-object in profile.php

Tags: php, html

As the error posted above, when the form is sumbitted, I get that error. I'm not 100% sure what may be the cause however I've provided hopefully all the parts you need. For reference Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE = 0.

This is use [this](https://github.com/JorgenPhi/php-snapchat).

Form HTML

```
    <form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
        Select Snap </label>
        <div class="col-lg-10" style="margin-bottom:24px;">
            <input type="file" id="file" class="filestyle" data-icon="false" name="file" data-classbutton="btn btn-default" data-classinput="form-control inline input-s">
                    <span class="help-block m-b-none">
                    Here, select the snapchat that you'd like to send. </span>
        </div>
    </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                Recipient </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-sm btn-default dropdown-toggle">
                <span class="dropdown-label" data-placeholder="Please select">
                Please select </span>
                <span class="caret">
                </span>
                </button>
                <ul name="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                    <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="d-s-c-1">
                    Option1 </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                                                                 <?php  
                                            $ff = count($r['friends']);
                                            for($xx = 0; $xx < $ff; $xx++)
                                                {
                                                echo '                      <li>
                    <a href="#">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="d-s-c-1[]" value="'.$r['friends'][$xx]->name.'"> 
                    '.$r['friends'][$xx]->name.'</a>
                    </li>';
                                                }
                                         ?>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        Remember me </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
                    Send Snap! </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Form PHP (same page)

```
   <?php
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
   else
     {
     $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
     $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
     $location = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
     $new = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 's/' . $filename);
     $aDoor = $_POST['d-s-c-1'];
     if(empty($aDoor)) 
     {
       echo("Please Select a recipient.");
     } 
     else
     {
       $N = count($aDoor);
    $id = $s->upload(
        Snapchat::MEDIA_IMAGE,
        file_get_contents($new)
    );
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
    $s->send($id, array($aDoor[$i]), 8);
    }
     }
     }
   ?>
```

upload() & send()

```
    public function upload($type, $data) {
            // Make sure we're logged in and have a valid access token.
            if (!$this->auth_token || !$this->username) {
                    return FALSE;
            }

            // To make cURL happy, we write the data to a file first.
            $temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'Snap');
            file_put_contents($temp, parent::encryptECB($data));

            if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '>=')) {
                    $cfile = curl_file_create($temp, ($type == self::MEDIA_IMAGE ? 'image/jpeg' : 'video/quicktime'), 'snap');
            }

            $media_id = strtoupper($this->username) . '~' . time();
            $timestamp = parent::timestamp();
            $result = parent::post(
                    '/upload',
                    array(
                            'media_id' => $media_id,
                            'type' => $type,
                            'data' => (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '>=') ? $cfile : '@' . $temp . ';filename=data'),
                            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                            'username' => $this->username,
                    ),
                    array(
                            $this->auth_token,
                            $timestamp,
                    ),
                    TRUE
            );

            unlink($temp);

            return is_null($result) ? $media_id : FALSE;
    }

/**
 * Sends a snap.
 *
 * @param string $media_id
 *   The media ID of the snap to send.
 * @param array $recipients
 *   An array of recipient usernames.
 * @param int $time
 *   The time in seconds the snap should be available (1-10). Defaults to 3.
 *
 * @return bool
 *   TRUE if successful, FALSE otherwise.
 */
public function send($media_id, $recipients, $time = 3) {
    // Make sure we're logged in and have a valid access token.
    if (!$this->auth_token || !$this->username) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $timestamp = parent::timestamp();
    $result = parent::post(
        '/send',
        array(
            'media_id' => $media_id,
            'recipient' => implode(',', $recipients),
            'time' => $time,
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'username' => $this->username,
        ),
        array(
            $this->auth_token,
            $timestamp,
        )
    );

    return is_null($result);
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `$s`?

Comment: $s is undefined.. and the first bit of the code is MASSIVE security vulnerability. You BLINDLY assume the upload succeeded and blindly use the user-provided filename to store it, meaning a malicious user scan scribble a file of their chosing ANYWHERE on your server.

Comment: $s is defined at the very top so that shouldn't be an issue